# Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in ..line 43

Tags: php, sql, database

hello eveyrone like the title said I've this error I want to know why and how . I want to understand too. here my code :

```
<div align = "center"> 
<form action = 'connection.php' method="post">

<p> Entrer vos informations  </p>

 <label for="usrUserName">Votre code d'usager </label> <input
id="usrUserName" name="usrUserName" /><br />

<label for="usrPassword">Votre mot de passe </label> <input
id="usrPassword" name="usrPassword" type="password" /><br />


<input type="submit" value="connection" />
</form>
```

for my connection.php

```
<?php 



    //hash md5
    $salt= MD5("00Salt02");


     if (isSet($_POST['usrUserName']) AND isSet ($_POST['usrPassword'])) 
        {

            // hash to sha256 
            $pass_hache = hash("sha256", ($salt + $_POST['usrPassword']));
            echo base64_encode($pass_hache);




            $mysqli  = new mysqli($host_name,$user_name,$pass_word, $database_name);
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }

    //select my user and pass
    $req = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE usrUserName = :usrUserName AND usrPassword = :usrPassword');
                    $req->execute(array('usrUserName' => $_POST['usrUserName'], 'usrPassword' => $pass_hache));

                    $resultat = $req->fetch();

                //if is not the result
                if (!$resultat) 
                {

                $_SESSION['usrUserName'] =  $_POST['usrUserName'];
                echo 'Mauvais identifiant ou mot de passe !';
                //return button
                ?>
                    <form action = 'login.php' method="post">
                        <input type="submit" value="retour" />
                    </form>

                <?php   
                }

            else {
    //connected hooray!     
                        session_start();
                                $_POST['usrUserName'] = $resultat['numero'];        
                    echo 'Vous etes connecté !';
                }
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'ERROR!';
    }
    ?>
```

Have any idea?

Comment: shouldn't it be: `$mysqli->execute`

Comment: you have to `bindparam` not in execute

Comment: You must have an error in your query, execute the query in console and check what's the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
$req = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE usrUserName = ? AND usrPassword = ?');
$req->bind_param("ss", $_POST['usrUserName'], $pass_hache);

$req->execute();
```

Comment: Think is the solution cuase now no error . ITs say my error message in echo so I need to adjust with my database Thanks!

Comment: great. Yes, in any case the syntax `usrUserName = :usrUserName` is invalid :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should do

```
$req->bind_param('usrUserName', $_POST['usrUserName']);
$req->bind_param('usrPassword', $pass_hache));
$req->execute();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in that was they said for trying this `code//select my user and pass
   $req = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE usrUserName = :usrUserName AND usrPassword = :usrPassword');
   $req->bind_param('usrUserName', $_POST['usrUserName']);
   $req->bind_param('usrPassword', $pass_hache);
   $req->execute();
   $resultat = $req->fetch();`

Comment: it means your prepare query didnt work, try to write it as @ponsciste posted